# How to refresh a webpage with the keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, browser

How can I refresh a web page without needing a mouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** or **<kbd>F5</kbd>** (and in some cases **<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>**) are the only two reliable ways of doing this.

Pressing **<kbd>Tab</kbd>** until you get to the refresh button can be unsuccessful if you don't start in the right place with the selection, and ultimately it's pretty unreliable. If you have any other keybindings set in the personal preferences of the browser or your OS, then you could use those, but the universal way to refresh a page without a mouse would be **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** or **<kbd>F5</kbd>**.

*Note:* On some laptops, the key combination is **<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>**. This can depend on how the function keys are configured in the BIOS. (Thanks to [Android Dev](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/android-dev) for pointing this out!)

Answer (score 1):

depending on the browser, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>

You can also, if the refresh button is visible, keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you get to it and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Obtained from the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)

Comment: Bonus! F5 works too. Double bonus! They work in any browser on any operating system and have worked like this for a very long time!

Comment: @AlexP Macs tend to prefer Cmd-R, I think